# Wordpress is showing paginated pages that doesn't exist

Tags: pagination, wordpress

I have a page template where I run a WP_Query

```
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=4'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

The issue I'm facing is that if you go to the site /page/100 it will show the template and it's not going to a 404 when It should.

My blog page under reading settings is another page and this is a custom template I'm doing.

I have read this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/non-existing-blog-pages-are-not-redirected-to-404 and tried all the functions and none of them work.

I also spent 3 hours searching on google without being able to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new **WP Query**. So I think you have to **reset** the **wp_postdata**.

[WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) offers sample code. You could try something like

```
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=4'.'&paged='.$paged);

if( ($wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        // Do here something with the post
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata(); // At the end reset your query
endif;
```

Comment: Hi pbaldauf thanks for your answer, I have tried resetting post data but if I go to domain.com/page/100 it is still showing the template instead of going to a 404

Comment: Another reason why it's showing the template instead of 404 could be a redirection rule (Either in .htaccess or a wp_rewrite_rule)

Answer (score 0):

While using WP_Query for displaying posts list you need to check by yourself if they are any posts for current page. Below is example code from [Wordpress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

 <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

 <!-- Start of the main loop. -->
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

 <!-- the rest of your theme's main loop -->

 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <!-- End of the main loop -->

 <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->

 <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
 <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

 <?php else : ?>
 <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Replace " _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); " 
with own error or function displaying 404 error.

Edit: Above code is of course example for Main Loop. In your particular case you need to call $wp_query->have_posts() and make sure it not evaluates to false. If it does display 404 error.

for example:

```
if(!$wp_query->have_posts()) {
    echo "404"; 
}
```

Or if you want server respond with HTTP code 404 instead of 200 then you should try something like this:

```
if(!$wp_query->have_posts()) {
status_header(404);
nocache_headers();
include( get_404_template() );
exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gemini, thanks for your answer. I think this is close but is not exactly what I'm looking for since this will just print 404 on page instead of going to 404 if the paginated page doesn't exist. Not sure if I'm right or not on this statement, please let me know if I'm not. I'm more talking that if you go to that page /page/100 it should go to 404 page instead of showing the template? not sure if the if/else statement is the correct way to do this? Let me know please and thanks again

Comment: For example if google crawls this page, it will be added to index since it's showing 404 but "it's not the physical 404 page" not sure if I'm self explaining well.

Comment: Another example, if you set this page as the "posts page" on settings -> reading then even if you don't have an if/else statement, once you go to the inexistent paginated page it will go straight to 404. This is without using a custom query, just the wp loop.

Comment: Yes wordpress handles 404 by itself for main loop. Since you want actual 404 then link you provided in your original question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/non-existing-blog-pages-are-not-redirected-to-404 contains functions forcing to display 404 error. You should add one such function (force_404 looks good) and call it instead of echo "404". However please note, that if you send anything to the browser before calling this function it might fail. Simplest option would be enabling php output buffering via php.ini or htaccess (if possible).

Comment: Yes, correct, but the issue I have is that I'm not on the main loop. The thing if I call the function on the else what I'm showing is the 404 content within the /page/200/, it's not a real 404 page (the title is not changed because it's not running on the header, and the status of $wp_query is also not changed since it's running after the loop.

Comment: A lot depends when exactly your code is executed. Is it template/plugin etc as well server settings. Not sure if you noticed the code I've updated in my reply above - this should give ACTUAL 404 error ( might be without title) - to verify this install Fiddler and check response code (this might be done also in Chrome). If you are still getting response code 200, then you should enable output buffering or move your code to plugin (so it execute before outputting anything else). You might also enable debugging in wordpress and check for errors most  likely you would see "headers already sent".